# How do i give water to thermal expansion machines

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I'm playing the ftb agrarian skies modpack, the problem is I don't know how to feed infinite water into the thermal expansion machines. Like the igneous extruder if I want it to make stone or obsidian I don't know how to give it infinite water.

I tried putting a water source behind it, it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a pipe to pipe the water to it. You'd also need a pump to draw water from the infinite water source, so an Aqueous Accumulator will be easier to use (it generates water on its own, place it in the corner of one 2x2 water source).

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble pumping in water, you can try changing the side config in the machine. You can use Mekanism pipes and a sink from CookingForBlockheads to pump in water without power (if you have those mods installed)